# 'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[keyof T]', but 'T[keyof T]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'

Tags: typescript

I have the following function to sum each property of an array of T and return it as T:

```js
export function sumProperties<T extends { [k: string]: number }>(values: T[]): T {
  return values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    (Object.keys(cur) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((k) => {
      acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + cur[k];
    })
    return acc;
  }, {} as T);
}
```

The line `acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + cur[k];` exhibits the problem.

Right now I have `Object.assign(acc, { [k]: (acc[k] || 0) + cur[k] });` as a workaround -- but would like not to use it. Can someone explain why this happens and provide a TypeScript safe solution?

Comment: Tip: provide a https://stackblitz.com/ example with your code so people can easily see the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T extends {[k: string]: number}` doesn't mean that values of the `T` are necessarily just numbers, the values might be some literal numbers as well, for instance `{type: 1}`:

```
// true
type Case1 = 1 extends number ? true : false

// false
type Case2 = number extends 1 ? true : false

const a: {type: 1} = {type: 1}

const a.type = 2; // error
```

Basically, `T` can have some sub-types of `number` as the value that can't be modified, and thus compiler can't be sure that you are able to modify the field.

Solution would be to completely remove the generics, however if you need them I can suggest something like this, though it won't be generic for the values, only for keys:

```
export function sumProperties<T extends { [k: string]: number }>(
  values: Record<keyof T, number>[],
): Record<keyof T, number> {
  return values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    (Object.keys(cur) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((k) => {
      acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + cur[k];
    });
    return acc;
  }, {} as T);
}
```

We are still accepting `T` as a generic, but declare values as `Record<keyof T, number>` to allow modifications.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM5IC2AClBGMLJsHgDwAqcoMwKAJnnAN5wDaA1gC58MKJhQBzALrCURAEaU4AXwB8ACgCwAKDhwAbgEMANkhrCASsDTQ2tfsACeEBHHoAaOHMKKoq3lLuOgCUlta29k4ubp7evqrcOnpQwDBIULhGpjQAdClsSGjA6uqGaGieaOnBcAC8CVxJenDqAPLyAFbWMDkOjnjqVVA1hpwAglBQho6Rzq70qsE5CNAAomUAFiX8NfWJus16ZWgCUnUtx6dwAD7XcAAMNQDUcEOnANxNesrBnwfJqXSuGOf2+ni4yjgozcvx0yh0QA)

Comment: Nearly perfect. I had to declare the input like this `<T extends Record<keyof T, number>>`. Otherwise the return type would not be convertible into T. After doing that the compiler does not complain any more.